# Flutter: how to get context from a class that shows a dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **page**, a **widget** an a **provider**.

The **page** has some elements in it but there is a widget that I need to use for other pages so that's why it's separated into another **widget**. This widget is just a dialog, so it's a class without any state:

```
class Difficulty {

  showModal() {
    var settingsController = context.watch<SettingsController>(); // this is what I'd need

    return showPlatformDialog(
    ...
```

So in my page, I call `Difficulty().showPlatformDialog()`, but I'd need the context from previous page or create a new one.

What's the best approach?

1. Pass it to `Difficulty()`
2. Pass it to `showModal()`
3. Create a `StatefulBuilder` or something else with its own context

same approach as https://github.com/filiph/tictactoe

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the global level navigation key that you can use context anywhere on the project and you don't have to pass the context.

You can checkout the my answer here I explained there how to use it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71922909/10936691

Comment: same error:
with that I get this error: "Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree."
This was fixed in other projects with `listen: false` but I don't have the provider created in the same way here, I use this .watch and not sure if I could pass same property to this

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the `BuildContext` as a parameter to `showPlatformDialog()`.

Example:

```
class Difficulty {

  showModal(BuildContext context) {
    var settingsController = context.watch<SettingsController>(); // this is what I'd need

    return showPlatformDialog(
                                ....
```

And call the function from the widget as

```
Difficulty().showPlatformDialog(context)
```

To answer your query, You can pass the `context` in any way like passing it to the function or creating a stateless/stateful widget.

I prefer the third approach though

Comment: with that I get this error: "Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree."
This was fixed in other projects with `listen: false` but I don't have the provider created in the same way here, I use this .watch and not sure if I could pass same property to this

Comment: are you using provider or riverpod?

Comment: I'm using provider:
providers: [
          Provider<SettingsController>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (context) => SettingsController(
              persistence: settingsPersistence,
            )..loadStateFromPersistence(),
          ),

Comment: to be more specific I'm using this approach: https://github.com/filiph/tictactoe